# How to display search results, and no result text if no result?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller, searchbar

I am trying to display only results instead of all data from the parse server. I tried different methods (mostly same), but I failed. I know that I miss something.

My question is how to display only results as well as no result text on the screen if no result.

You can find my approach below.

Thank you very much in advance.

```js
class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    
    var searchActive : Bool = false
    var data:[PFObject]!
    var noteObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    var filtered:[PFObject]!
    
    
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var searchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        search()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: .valueChanged)

        self.tableView?.addSubview(refresher)
        self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = tableView.rowHeight;
        
       

        
    }
    
    @objc func refresh() {
        print("Refreshed")
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        search()
    }
    
    
    @objc func search(searchText: String? = nil){
        
        let query = PFQuery(className: "NewUsers")
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.current() as Any)
        if(searchText != nil){
            query.whereKey("name", contains: searchText)
            
            
        }
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            
            
            
            if error == nil {
                if let cars = objects {
                    
                    
                    for object in cars {
                        if (object as PFObject?) != nil {
                           
                            self.data = objects
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                           
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filtered.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text
        let query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "NewUsers")
        if searchController.isActive == true  {
            query.whereKey("name", matchesRegex: searchText!, modifiers: "i")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (results, error) in
            self.filtered = results
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        print(searchText as Any)
        
        
    }
    
    var shouldUseSearchResult : Bool {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            if searchText.isEmpty {
                return false
            }
        }
        return searchController.isActive
    }
    
    
    


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if data != nil {
            return self.data.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell

        let obj = self.data[indexPath.row]
        
        self.name = (obj["name"] as? String)!
        self.surname = (obj["surname"] as? String)!
        self.birthdate = (obj["birthday"] as? String)!
        self.age = (obj["age"] as? String)!
        self.city = (obj["city"] as? String)!
        
        cell.dateLabel.text = ": " + birthday
        cell.ageLabel.text = ": \(age)"
        cell.userLabel.text = ": " + name + " " + surname
        

        return cell
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        
        
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
        
        
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        search(searchText: searchText)
        
    }
    
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        
        return true
    }
    
    
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        
    }
    
    

}
```

Comment: just check if searchactive and data count is 0 then display the no results text in a label or in a cell by returning 1 count for tableview rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if (self.data.count == 0)
    {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
        noDataLabel.text          = "No Result Found."
        noDataLabel.textColor     = UIColor.red
        noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tablevİEW.separatorStyle  = .none
    }
        return 1

}
```

`self.arrayDealPage` is `array` & `self.dealsTable` is `tableView` Hope, it might help u and  `delegate` and `datasource` protocol added.

Comment: I have a problem. Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        if (self.data.count == 0)
        {
            let noDataLabel: UILabel     = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
           ...
        }
        return 1
    }

Comment: check this line :-let noDataLabel: and i have recently used that code and it is working fine for me

Comment: the Data is my array

Comment: plz change ur details in my code it will resolve ur issue @TomBulut

Comment: Here is the problem: if (self.data.count == 0)

Comment: I solved it as if (self.data == nil). But it's not the complete solution of my question. How to display only results?

Comment: u want to show results when search from search bar @TomBulut

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: @TomBulut if i m able to resolve ur issue upvote the answer so that it will help other people